# Best way to go about changing Python/Tkinter program to Electron?

Tags: python, tkinter, electron

I was given a project that was already done and written in Python and utilizes Tkinter for the GUI. I am supposed to rewrite the Python project and use Electron (for cross-platform). I don't know if I should just start from scratch and rewrite the whole thing or if there's a way to integrate the already written Python code? Any advice would be great, thanks!

Comment: Basically `Electron` application is like a web application using JavaScript, HTML and CSS, therefore it is not possible to integrate Python code and tkinter module (which depends on `Tcl/Tk` library).  Python and tkinter are normally supported in current popular OS, why do you want to migrate the application?

Comment: It's for an internship so it's not really my decision. My best bet is to just rewrite the program then?

Comment: Yes, sort of basically.